# How to hide the cell in tableview if json data nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to hide the cell collectionview in section if json data is nil. im loading collectionview in a tableview cell.my code is belowim showing array of images in collection view i have used third party for horizontalautomatic scroll as third party for collection view

```
func setCollectionData(_collectionData: [Any]) {
    self.collectionData = _collectionData as NSArray      
    collectionViewObj.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:0), animated: true)       
    for i in 0 ..< collectionData.count {
        self.strings = StringClass()
        self.strings.vehicleImage = (collectionData[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "img_name") as? String                        
        self.strings.vehicleTitle=(collectionData[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "p_name") as? String                  
        self.modelArray.append(self.strings)                        
    }    
    collectionViewObj.reloadData()
}            
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if self.collectionData.count >= 4 {
        return 4
    }
    else
    {
    return collectionData.count
    }
}    

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductCollectionViewCustomCell", for: indexPath)as! ProductCollectionViewCustomCell        
    strings = modelArray[indexPath.row]        
    cell.ProductTitleLabel.text =  strings.vehicleTitle        
    let URLBaseString = "http://vehiclebuzzzz.com/"        
    let url = URL(string:URLBaseString .appending(strings.vehicleImage!))        
    let dataurl = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)    
    cell.productImageViewObj.image=UIImage(data: dataurl!)                
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Remove the data you want to hide from data source and reload table view, that's the easiest solution.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to ask question you are asking for tableview cell & your code seems collectionview ?

Comment: i am loading collection view in tableview cell .. i have to  load array1 in first section of the collection view and array2 in second section of the collection view. if array1 is empty i want to hide that section

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

override this method and return zero size `CGSize.zero` if the json data is nil else return actual size of cell

OR

remove nil data from array and call `collectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Update the `collectionData` array with the new data & then perform `collectionViewObj.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

-If you does not want show collection view. just hide the collection view until you get the data.
-When you data make it visible